English children's book, possibly from the 50's, about a boy, a girl, and their dog who stay in a valley menaced by a witch and her fox familiar
A boy and a girl, accompanied by their rather vain dog, go to stay in a valley that is menaced by a witch and her familiar, a fox. The children are tasked to assist the guardian of the valley, who is a dis-used mill (I think a windmill, but I'm far from sure).
I remember the fox making a fool of the dog more than once, and the witch sending mosquitos as spies in the night, which were both details I found clever.
I believe the witch is defeated, but that the mill itself burns down.

Perhaps "The Company at the Mill" by Muriel Hooper.
I found this review on Growing Point, Volumes 1-2, 1962:

...confused and uncertain in its impact. I can't feel that the  author
really believes in her priggish heroine Rosemary (who plans to turn
the Mill into a home for sick animals) or in the talking animals
(headed by a cavalry horse whose full title is the Comte de l'Haute
École) who band themselves against Mrs. Ragwort the witch and her
gang. The fact that the Mill itself (or himself) is more or less
humanised makes it even more necessary that we should know why the
witch wants to blow it up, but we never do know, and the war is merely
a nasty affair...

From the School Librarian and School Library Review, Volumes 12-13, 1964:

Rosemary and her brother Tom turn an old mill into a rest home for
tired animals, which include, in addition to the conventional farm
creatures, a delightful cavalry horse by the name of the Comte de
l'Haute Ecole, fatigued by the pleasures of Vienna, and a lion. This
company forms itself into a garrison in defence of the harvest, which
is threatened by the creatures of the wild woods, led by the sinister
Mrs. Ragwort.


Clearly the right book, but — judging by the review, it's clear I'd forgotten almost every element of the plot!
